# How to convert single row data into a single column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, transformation

I have a table like:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
A        B        C        D
```

wants to convert it as:

```
Column
A
B
C
D
```

Without using this union all in oracle:

```
select column1 as Column from dual
union all
select column2 as Column from dual
union all
select column3 as Column from dual
union all
select column4 as Column from dual
```

Comment: You can try with unpivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [unpivot](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

```
select v
from (
  SELECT 'A' column1,'B' column2,'C' column3,'D' column4  from dual
) t
unpivot
(
  v  for val in (column1,column2,column3,column4)
) u;
```

sqlfiddle:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b2105e1010b332ce5b702eba7bfa7f2d