# Convert single row result into two column result. Unpivot error 'expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression'

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

**Please read only EDIT section which is more relevant now.**

I have table in oracle 12c database, say table_1.

[image: table_1]

I have to run a simple SQL which returns only 1 row and all columns from from table_1. Say like

```
select * from table_1 where col_1 = 65
```

But the result I want is like:

[image: ExpectedResult]

I did some search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962636/how-to-convert-single-row-data-into-a-single-column-in-oracle) link which is very similar to what i want.
But I was only able to get the first column in the expected result by folowing it. I am unable to get actual data in the second column of the expected result.

So far I was able to write only:

```
select v
  from (
        select 'col_1' as col_1, 'col_2' as col_2, 'col_3' as col_3, 'col_4' as col_4 from dual
       ) t
unpivot
(
  v for val in (col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4)
) u;
```

How can I add the second column and the condition `where col_1 = 65`?

**EDIT: (Above part is less relevant now)**

I fount [this](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_DT38BTKONDYSUSJYEUPQ7V1QR.html) link where there us unpivot example which I could use.

```
select * from olympic_medal_tables
```

Gives:
[image: olympic_medal_tables]

```
desc olympic_medal_tables

Name          Null? Type        
------------- ----- ----------- 
NOC                 VARCHAR2(3) 
GOLD_MEDALS         NUMBER      
SILVER_MEDALS       NUMBER      
BRONZE_MEDALS       NUMBER
```

Following SQL gives me what I could use, but I don't want the NOC column in the result:

```
select * from olympic_medal_tables   
unpivot (medal_count for medal_colour in (   
  gold_medals as 'GOLD',   
  silver_medals as 'SILVER',   
  bronze_medals as 'BRONZE'
));
```

Result:
[image: result]

So when I add NOC as well (so it is not added as a column in the result) like:

```
select * from olympic_medal_tables   
unpivot (medal_count for medal_colour in (   
  gold_medals as 'GOLD',   
  silver_medals as 'SILVER',   
  bronze_medals as 'BRONZE',
  noc as 'NOC'
));
```

I get error: `ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression` on line 6 `Error at Line: 44 Column: 3`

I have tried using TO_NUMBER and TO_CHAR as well but then I get various syntax errors.
**Question:** How can I get expected result with just 2 columns. Is it possible with this approach using unpivot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option, which requires you to first select *one row*, and then apply `UNPIVOT` to it:

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2, col3, col4) as
  2    (select '12', 'hfkds' , 'hk435k'  , '32'  from dual union
  3     select '34', 'ldkfgj', 'fsjd4653', '324' from dual union
  4     select '65', 'ifd'   , 'dkfjs345', '23'  from dual union
  5     select '87', 'dg'    , '345jh'   , '65'  from dual
  6    ),
  7  one_row as
  8    (select * From test
  9     where col1 = '65'
 10    )
 11  select *
 12  from one_row
 13  unpivot (col_value for col_name in
 14              (col1 as 'col1', col2 as 'col2', col3 as 'col3', col4 as 'col4'));

COL_ COL_VALU
---- --------
col1 65
col2 ifd
col3 dkfjs345
col4 23

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you Littlefoot.
I was able to use your suggestion and tweak it little for columns with different data types and it did what I was looking for.